# Cant transform or move object with pivot in object mode

Tags: transforms

All of sudden I can't click on pivot points so I can't transform my object. But can do it with shortcuts G S R only
What have I done?

Ive tried to press N and uncheck everything there, also there is no "only location" checked nothing is work [image]